citations exported as footnotes with org-cite
A cite inserted in an org-mode document is exported to pdf or html as a footnote; i.e. [cite:@TillyTarrow2007] if exported shows as (Tilly & Tarrow 2007) in a footnote.
This is a minimal example of my doc working on Debian bookworm, emacs 28.2, org-mode 9.5.5
#+LaTeX_CLASS: article
#+bibliography: ~/Dropbox/org/minimalTest.bib
#+cite_export: csl ~/Dropbox/org/csl/apa.csl
This is my citation
[cite/t/cf:@Tilly2007]  to create Tilly & Tarrow (2007)
For some reason I can't figure out, the citation shows up as a footnote
#+print_bibliography:
I expect the exported citation to merge in the paragraph; i.e. this is a reference to (Tilly & Tarrow 2007)
